# 'Probe' function in linux device driver not called when device tree definition is within 'reserved memory' node

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

When my driver definition in the linux device tree is references a node in the 'reserved-memory' section, as such:

```
reserved-memory {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            ranges;

            testmod_reserved: testmod_reserved@41000000 {
                compatible = "ibd,testmod";
                reg = <0x20000000 0x1000>;
            };
    };

testmod@41000000 {
    memory-region = <&testmod_reserved>;
};
```

The probe function within my 'testmod' kernel module is not called (upon doing an 'insmod testmod'. However if I define it outside the reserved-memory node, as such:

```
test_mod: testmod@41000000 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        ranges;
        compatible = "ibd,testmod";
        reg = <0x20000000 0x1000>;
};
```

Then everything is fine, 'probe' is called upon 'insmod'.

I have confirmed the device tree is being parsed/loaded correctly, by perusing the '/proc/device-tree/' information. The phandles, memory definitions, reg values etc are all correct.

I haven't been able to find any information on why this would be occurring.?

Answer (score 0):

Read through reserved-memory documentation in kernel: 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt

### /reserved-memory/ child nodes

Each child of the reserved-memory node specifies one or more regions of
reserved memory. Each child node may either use a 'reg' property to
specify a specific range of reserved memory, or a 'size' property with
optional constraints to request a dynamically allocated block of memory.